# Is it possible to add an Apple compatible remote control to an audio cable for headphones?

Tags: iphone, headphones

I'm wondering whether there is some TRRS extension cable available which has a remote control for volume and play/pause that would allow to extend any headphones by a remote control, or alternatively whether I could build one myself using the remote control from broken Apple earbuds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are lots of them, check [eBay](https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_odkw=ios%20extension%20cable%20remote&_osacat=0&_from=R40&_trksid=p2045573.m570.l1313.TR0.TRC0.H0.Xiphone%20extension%20cable%20remote.TRS0&_nkw=iphone%20extension%20cable%20remote&_sacat=0), amazon, probably aliexpress.

Keywords I used are: [iphone extension cable remote](https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_odkw=ios%20extension%20cable%20remote&_osacat=0&_from=R40&_trksid=p2045573.m570.l1313.TR0.TRC0.H0.Xiphone%20extension%20cable%20remote.TRS0&_nkw=iphone%20extension%20cable%20remote&_sacat=0).

Most of them have a microphone as well.